# For two randomly generated 4-digit numbers, what is the probability that two numbers won't have any digit common between them?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider that numbers between (and including) $0000$ and $9999$ are being drawn from a uniform distribution. What is the probability that two such randomly chosen numbers would have no digits common between them? [Note: numbers that have less that 4-digits, are prefixed with the requisite number of zeros (e.g. $0575$, $0013$, etc.).]

Examples of valid pairs could be:

$1234$ and $0556$

$0000$ and $3333$

$7712$ and $3344$

I have counted the number of all such pairs using a simple Python program and it is turning out to be $19550250$. So the probability is turning out to be $\frac{19550250}{10^8}$. The problem is, I am unable to come up with any analytical way of arriving at this result.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that the two numbers (with leading zeroes allowed) should not have any common digit between them, but that individual numbers can have repeat digits, so $0023$ and $4444$ would be a valid pair ?

Comment: You could split the count into cases based on the number of distinct digits in each string. Use binomial coefficients to count the ways of selecting the digits for each string and inclusion-exclusion when counting the ways of arranging the selected digits (to ensure all of them are used).

Comment: @trueblueanil yes!

Comment: Or probably simpler: find the distribution for the number of distinct digits in the first string, and then in each of the four cases compute the probability that the second string avoids those digits.

Comment: @Karl I tried both of these ways. Maybe I'm miscounting something, because, the results are not matching!

Comment: I have just posted an answer, and it looks like it is similar, or even the same, as what @Karl suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first count the total number of ways to choose the pair. This is simply $10^8$ as there are $8$ total digits. But this counts e.g. $\{1234,5678\}$ and $\{5678,1234\}$ as different pairs, so we when we do subsequent calculations, we will need to take into account that the pairs are ordered.

With that in mind, we can split the problem into four cases:

Case #1: The first number has $1$ unique digit.

We have $10$ choices for the first number ($0000,1111,\ldots,9999$), and $9^4$ choices for the second number ($9$ available digits for the $4$ digit slots), for a total of $10\cdot9^4=65610$ pairs for this case.

Case #2: The first number has $3$ unique digits.

(Skipping $2$ unique digit case for now because it is easier this way)

We have $\frac{4!}{2!\cdot2}\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8=4320$ choices for the first number and $7^4$ choices for the second number, for a total of $4320\cdot7^4=10372320$ pairs for this case.

Case #3: The first number has $4$ unique digits.

We have $10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7=5040$ choices for the first number and $6^4$ choices for the second number, giving us $5040\cdot6^4=6531840$ pairs for this case.

Case #4: The first number has $2$ unique digits.

There are $10000$ numbers total with $4$ digits, so there are $10000-10-4320-5040=630$ numbers with $2$ unique digits, and $8^4$ choices for the second number, giving us a total of $630\cdot8^4=2580480$ pairs for this case.

Adding the cases together gives us $65610+10372320+6531840+2580480=19550250$ pairs in total, out of $10^8$ possible.

This gives the probability as:
$$\boxed{\frac{19550250}{10^8}}$$

Comment: could you please elaborate Case 2 a bit? Thanks!

Comment: @TDG Yep for sure! So the only way to get $3$ unique digits is to have $2$ of the digits be the same, and the other two digits being different. We can represent this as permutations of the "string" $AABC$, where $A,B,C$ are distinct digits. We can find the number of permutations of $AABC$ to be $\frac{4!}{2!1!1!}$. We then have $10$ choices for choosing a digit for $A$, and $\binom92=\frac{9\cdot8}2$ choices for choosing the digits for $B$ and $C$ (I combined the $2$ into the previous fraction mentioned and expanded out the $9\cdot8$ in my actual answer).

Comment: And the reason why I say it will be easier to leave the $2$ unique digit case for last is because for that case, we can either have the string as $AABB$ or $AAAB$, which will complicate things more than it needs to.

Comment: Thanks! Beautifully explained!

Comment: @TDG No problem! And I might as well mention that if you really wanted to calculate the amount of numbers with $2$ unique digits as needed for Case #4 (calculated to be $630$ by subtracting the amount from the other cases), all you need to realize is that the permutations of the strings $AABB$ and $AAAB$ are all covered if you convert $1$ through $14$ to binary and replacing $0$ with $A$ and $1$ with $B$ (For example, $5$ -> $0101_2$ -> $ABAB$). This suggests that there are $14$ permutations total, and you might be able to carry out the calculations from here if you want to.

Comment: You could have done "$2$ unique digits" with ${10 \cdot 9}\cdot(2^3-1)=630$ or a variety of other ways

Comment: @Henry Where does $2^3-1$ come from?

Comment: @AidenChow $10$ ways of choosing the first digit, $9$ ways of choosing the different digit, then $2^3-1$ ways of putting the first digit in the other $3$ places or not (they cannot all be the first digit)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative route on base of [PIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

For $k$ distinct digits the number of $4$-digit numbers that contain these digits equals:$$\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}i(-1)^i(10-i)^4$$
This can be found with the inclusion/exclusion principle.

Then - again using PIE - we find that the number of ordered pairs of $4$-digit numbers (allowing $0$ as first digit) that have no digits in common equals:$$\sum_{k=0}^4\binom{10}k(-1)^k\left(\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}i(-1)^i(10-i)^4\right)^2=$$$$10^8-10(10^4-9^4)^2+45(10^4-2\cdot9^4+8^4)^2-120(10^4-3\cdot9^4+3\cdot8^4-7^4)^2+$$$$210(10^4-4\cdot9^4+6\cdot8^4-4\cdot7^4+6^4)^2=$$$$10^8-10\cdot11826721+45\cdot948676-120\cdot41616+210\cdot576=19550250$$